# Storing AES Key in Android Device Securely

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt a list of strings specified by the user. The AES key used to encrypt and decrypt this data must be saved on the device so it can be used to decrypt the data whenever the user needs to. I have read that using Keystore is a good option for storing keys, but most of the guides I have read about it relate it to signing your application, which is not exactly what I want. My application requires the user to input a password, which then decrypts the String data using the key which is unlocked with the password. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to answer your question without having you define "securely" in a precise manner. Are you talking about security against other apps? Security against other users? Security against theft of device? Or security against loss?

In addition, what level of security are you talking about? Is the data being encrypted under the given key sensitive enough to warrant serious considerations about how the key can be stored?

To my understanding, if the data is of highly sensitive nature, you should derive the key directly from the password using a password-based key-derivation function such as PBKDF #2, Bcrypt or Scrypt. In this way, the key material needs not be stored on your device directly.

If you intend to store the master encrypting key for whatever reason, encrypt under the password key and store as a Base64 string under SharedPreferences with `MODE_PRIVATE` to protect it against other apps. Even if the key was recovered by a malicious user/device theft, without the proper password key, the key material itself is useless.

If you wanted to protect the key against loss, you shouldn't store the key on the device but rather on your own server, again encrypted under the password key so that database compromise will not result in data compromise as well.

In all, I'd suggest you try not to store any sort of private key onto the device itself and instead used the password-derived key as your master key for all cryptographic operations. Leave the keystores for private-keys generated in public-key cryptography and known public key certificates.

Comment: I have previously tried PBKDF2, but each time, it generated a different key each time, even though the password was the same.

Comment: Also, even if I am to generate the PBKDF2 key that has to be the same each time, wouldn't I have to hardcode the salt, which could be retrieved by an attacker?

Comment: @gl321 Randomly generate the salt on the first time and store that in a shared preference. The salt and parameter of the algorithm are not private in that they can be retrieved by an attacker without any security risk, just make sure the salt is random per user (disables generation of a rainbow table for all users). Once the initial key has been generated, make sure the salt is not lost (perhaps stored on your own server as well). The encoding key can be periodically changed next time the user logs in, with generation of a new salt.

Comment: I believe I have to decrypt and re-encrypt the strings if the key is changes. Is there any solution to this? Also, should the IV parameters be hardcoded too?
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @gl321 Don't hardcode anything. Let them be randomly generated when needed and then stored. If you use the same (generated) seed with PBKDF #2/Bcrypt or Scrypt you will arrive at the same key. If you do need to change the key for whatever reason, you would need to decrypt and then re-encrypt everything and there is just no way around that. I'd suggest only perform a key change when majority of data has already been decrypted for the user, that you you'd merely need to ren-encrypt the data as appropriate. Its hard to gauge the needs of your system without knowing the precise nature of its task.

Comment: So I've implemented lots of this, but whenever I Base64-decode the decrypted text, some of the letters are way off and many show as a question mark...

Comment: @gl321 Probably just a problem with your character set. Try explicitly setting it to UTF-8 and see what happens.

Comment: I have actually specified it as UTF-8, yet it just prints out lots of strange question marks all over the decrypted string and a bit of characters that are off.

Comment: @gl321 Your queries are starting to get off-topic with regard to this question. I suspect its an issue with your base64 encoder/decoder. If you have further queries I suggest you consider posting subsequent new questions further describing your issue (considering what other questions already exist). I wouldn't mind advising you in a SO room if it comes to that. As an additional note its hard to debug an issue from my perspective without a full understanding of the underlying system, so my answers will only be more and more limited as they get more specific.